# Customer Portal Access to specific Library Files

Tags: community, customer-community, customer-community-plus

I have a need to allow customer community users access to specific files based on a field on their contact records.  Is this possible?  I am thinking that I could have a Library that I would add the files to that they need access.  I am not seeing how to add only some of the customer community users to a public group to give them access to the library.  Thoughts?  I have the basic Customer Community portal licenses.  If this could be done with the Customer Community Plus licenses, I would buy them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Customer Community Plus licenses you could do Apex Managed Sharing which would make what you want to do possible. I do not know a way of doing what you're asking about using criteria-based sharing rules with a basic Customer Community license.